# Terraform deletes google secrets version

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-secret-manager

My code is as below:

```
# Enable API for Secret Manager
resource "google_project_service" "secret_manager" {
  project            = "buoyant-valve-34"
  service            = "secretmanager.googleapis.com"
  disable_on_destroy = true
}

resource "google_secret_manager_secret" "secret-basic" {
  secret_id = "new-secret-by-me"
  project   = "buoyant-valve-34"
  replication {
    automatic = true
  }
}

resource "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "secret-version-basic" {
  secret      = google_secret_manager_secret.secret-basic.id
  secret_data = "very-secret"
}
```

The problem is when I change the secret_data (say "very-secret2") the terraform destroys the previous version instead of keeping it as it is.
I have also tried adding the below lifecycle block but no help it shows **Error:** *Instance cannot be destroyed*

```
lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
```

How to avoid this issue ?
(In image please ignore version 6 I have created it manually)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2q70i.png)

Comment: I don't think this is avoidable with the current implementation of that resource type in the `hashicorp/google` provider. There's a feature request open for optionally disabling instead of destroying ([#11652](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/11652)) but it doesn't seem to be implemented yet and so isn't a solution currently.

Comment: @MartinAtkins, Thanks you for quick reply. Yes you are right. The only only option left is to use the latest version when working with secrets using terraform.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. [Google's Secret Manager API](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.secrets.versions) does not allow editing an existing version, only enable, disable and destroy. If you edit the value of the secret in your code, Terraform will want to destroy the existing version and create a new one.

When using the secret, you should always access the latest version via "projects/{project_id}/secrets/{secret_id}/versions/latest"

Comment: Thanks, I agree as there is no other option left.